# How to stop resizing the graph axis in tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-desktop

I want to stop resizing the graph axis (x,y), if any filter on the data is used in tableau. Can anyone helpe with this?

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the axis to edit its characteristics (or right click on it and choose edit axis)

By default, the axis upper and lower bounds are set automatically based on the range of data that appears. If you wish to fix one or both ends to a constant value, just change that setting in the axis editing dialog.

You’ll see a push-pin icon on the axis to remind you that the axis bounds are pinned. That reminder is useful because if there is data that is beyond the bounds of the axis, it will be clipped and not shown.

BTW, this is the exactly the same thing that happens when you zoom in on a map or chart, you’re pinning the axes to display only part of the region.